# file upload be accessed to send through ajax POST?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, file-upload

here's the situation

Within a single form
1) User clicks on the 'browse' button, which opens a dialog to choose an image file to upload. 
i.e.

```
input id='img_upload' name="ufile" type="file" value="Browse"/>
```

2) With file selected, user then clicks a button 'Upload file' button, which calls a js function 
i.e.

```
input type='button' id='uload' class='save2' value='Upload file' onclick='upload_img()' >   </input>
```

What I would like upload_img() to do is send the contents of the browse via POST through something like AJAX to a .php file called image_upload.php, which will save the img and output an  tag displaying the img file. I have an iframe which displays the contents of image_upload.php

If possible, how can I access the contents of a 'browse' and send it through POST

Cheers!

**EDIT** Sorry I forgot that a strict subset of html is supported, so I had to remove the left most <

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the user needing flash and that you have to use jquery, uploadify does pretty much exactly what you just requested. You control the callback so you can do whatever you need after the file uploads.

http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: Nope, flash won't fly. Users are not required to install anything

Comment: Fair enough - I've heard use of iframes to contain your browse button to handle similar tasks, but I myself have never tried to do that.

Comment: Oh, so have the entire form be inside an iframe and handle uploads that way? Hrrrrmmm, that's an interesting idea, I'll go give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're hoping to pull the file path from the file selection action, send it to the php script, which will use the file path to upload the actual image.

In short: this is **not possible**. The PHP script is executed on the server, and therefore has no access to the client's filesystem. However, this does not mean that AJAX file uploads are impossible altogether. There are several jQuery-utilizing solutions that should do the trick. [This article](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/) features seven of them.

Comment: No, my desire is to simulate the functionality of a 'submit' being pressed. When a submit is pressed we send the file via $HTTP_POST_FILES, where I can play with it. Is it possible to send this kind of data through Ajax by reading what was browsed for? Does that make sense?

Comment: Unfortunately, form submission is synchronous and requires a page refresh, and it is only during this event that data from `<input type="file"` fields are streamed to the server to be accessed in the $_FILES array. AJAX file upload plugins (like those in my link above) often use a nested iframe to submit a form synchronously without refreshing the parent page, or use a small SWF to stream the file to the server via Flash.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. I wasn't sure exactly when such data was sent. I found mention of using iframes while wandering the web, I'll give that a shot. Thanks for the knowledge.